# Single WCF channel performance vs multiple channels

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an application that reuses the same WCF channel over and over again. I keep a static reference through a factory object. I wonder if this is good pratice or that I should open x channels and round robin all services calls over these channels instead of using the single channel?

Do these services calls get queued if using only 1 channel or does the same happen when I would use x channels?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a single channel factory for all requests but different channels should be constructed for each request. Never reuse channels. They are not expensive to create and are not thread safe. What is expensive to create is the channel factory. It is thread safe and can be reused. Of course if the channel factory get into a faulted state you might need to reopen it.

Comment: So holding on to the ICommunicationObject returned by _channelFactory.CreateChannel() is not a good idea? I now keep 1 channel open for all requests, I don't do a _channelFactory.CreateChannel() for each call, I reuse the static one created the first time.

Comment: @Bjorn Bailleul, not a good idea at all. Instances returned by `_channelFactory.CreateChannel()` should live as short as possible and never be reused. As I said the `CreateChannel` call is not expensive. It is very fast. You can call it for each request. What is expensive is the creation of the channel factory. This is what you could cache.

Comment: @Darin - Do you have reference or link for "use a different channel for each call". This blog is one of the most referenced articles on channel factories and its first best practice is "Reuse the same proxy":

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx

Comment: @ErnieL, `Reuse the same proxy` means `reuse the same channel factory`, not `reuse the same channel`. There is a big difference.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov "Reuse the same proxy" means "reuse channel". See example provided by the author in link: ISimpleContract proxy = factory.CreateChannel();  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2007/10/25/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared/

Answer (score 6):

@Darin Dimitrov

> **Reuse the same proxy**
>   In many cases, you would want to reuse the same proxy. This has the best performance. It is especially true when you use security features since the initial security negotiation can have high cost.

proxy equals channel. if you look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/26/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared.aspx), you can see the following code snippet:

```
ISimpleContract proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)proxy).Open();
```

Furthermore, if you plan to work with sessions, you don't want to establish a new session for each request (by creating a new channel/proxy each time).